# Regular expression to replace match keywords outside html tags AND anchor (a) tag text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex

I am developing an asp.net application. I want to add a keyword linking system.

I want to make the keyword a hyper-link to another page. But, I should not link the keyword if its currently linked (to any page). For example:

```
it is a <a href="http://www.somesite.com">linked keyword</a> and it should be a linked keyword.
```

should convert to:

```
it is a <a href="http://www.somesite.com">linked keyword</a> and it should be a linked <a href="http://newlycreatedLink.com">keyword</a>.
```

As you can see, the first keyword should be left intact.

Could you help me please to solve this problem?

I've found [this link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1443955/5612191.aspx?p=True&t=635262200031494155&pagenum=1) in asp.net forums. But I should tune the answer to exclude currently linked keywords. I've searched everywhere but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if the keywords is "outside", [look ahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

- `(?=` if after the keyword there's an opening `<tag` or the `$` end
- `[^<>]*` any amount of characters, that are NOT `>` OR `<`
- followed by `(?:<\w|$)` where `\w` is a shorthand to word-charcters `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

So the pattern could look like:

```
String pattern = @"(?i)\bkeyword\b(?=[^<>]*(?:<\w|$))";

String replacement = @"<a href=\"http://newlycreatedLink.com\">\0</a>";
```

Put the keyword into word-boundaries `\b` and used `(?i)` i modifier for case insensitive.

So this would only replace `keyword` that is followed by an opening-tag or the end.

---

*UPDATE*: To replace `keyword` also "inside" tags, that don't end up with `</a` add `|<\/[^a]`:

```
String pattern = @"(?i)\bkeyword\b(?=[^<>]*(?:<\w|<\/[^a]|$))";
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonny, its almost what I am looking for, but the problem is it will ignore text inside all tags. For example, this will not replace `<p>keyword</p>`

Comment: @KiNG If you know what additional tags you allow the keyword to be "inside", might want to *whitelist* those, e.g.: `(?i)\bkeyword\b(?=[^<>]*(?:<\w|<\/p|$))` ... added OR `|<\/p`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions for sophisticated HTML parsing like this. Use a proper HTML parser instead — [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/362634).

Comment: LOL :)) That was really funny :) I tried to use a DOM document parser, but the overhead for my simple task is high. I don't want to parse html with regex, its a simple replace and I thought a small change to linked regex `(?<!<[^>]*)keyword(?<![^>]*<)` could make what I need. But my regex knowledge is real low :(